# Pyomo - Gurobi Persistent - Change parameter values between solve

Tags: pyomo, gurobi

I'm actually trying to use Gurobi in persistent mode with Pyomo.
I've modeled (using pyomo blocks) an energy system with a battery and solve the energy/power balance at every time step, updating the battery SOC_INIT before each solve.
It works fine when I use gurobi in none persistent mode.

With gurobi-persistent, I update the SOC_INIT param and resolve. Nothing happens, the solver does nothing, and keeps all variables values from the previous solve.

Roughly, What I have:

The SOC_INIT Param is mutable

SOC = SOC_INIT + Energy exchange during timestep (SOC is a Var)

I've tried the solver.add_var/solver.update_var on SOC variable, changed SOC_INIT from Param to Var.

What am I missing ? Documentation about this is not very helpful...

Would someone share a proper way to do that, i.e, updating some Params/Vars between solves ? a code snippet would be nice :)

Thanks for your help.
Max.

Answer (score 0):

First get the number of solutions

```
n_of_solutions = m.SolCount
```

Then loop over each solution by using

```
 for solution in range(0, n_of_solutions):
        m.setParam(GRB.Param.SolutionNumber, solution)
        # do something
```

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try!